# Move my dao from gatcoin to own Mist-wallet

Tags: dao

I have DAO in gatecoin and got note to only can take it out with mist-wallet.
Now I have a Mist.wallet running on my lap-top and dontknow if how to go on?

Do youknow the way to transfer,parts or all of it or any other proposal? 
Should I let it stand there for something to expected to happen?